# How to enqueue and dequeue without using add() and remove()?

Tags: java, queue

****My attempt so far****

```
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;
public class QueueQuiz {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Queue beverages = new LinkedList();
        beverages.offer("shoes");
        beverages.offer("ball"); //enqueue ball without using add()
        System.out.println(beverages.peek() + " is queued first.");
        beverages.poll(); //dequeue ball without using remove()
        System.out.println("Element(s) in the queue: " + beverages);
    }
}
```

I already dequeue the "ball", but it pops when I call the element in the queue not "shoes". How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to enqueue without using add

By using `.offer()`.

> How to dequeue without using remove

By using `.poll()`.

In other words, you're doing it.

> I dequeue already the "ball" but it pops when I call the element in the queue not "shoes"

Of course. You put your shoes in the drawer. Then, you put the ball in the drawer, which moves the shoes to the back of the cupboard. Then, you open the drawer and take the first thing your hands can touch back out, which is the ball.

The drawer now contains just the shoes.

Comment: what should i change so the remaining element is "shoes"?

Comment: Queues work as FIFO, what you want can't be done with a queue. try `Deque<T> x = new ArrayDeque<T>();` and use methods `push` and `pop`.

Comment: can't change to that. my only option to change are offer, poll, and peek.

Comment: Then, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

For enqueue, use offer(), and for dequeue, use poll().

You are doing it right.

But Queue follows FIFO (First In First Out).

```
    beverages.offer("shoes");
```

["shoes"]

```
    beverages.offer("ball");
```

["shoes","ball"]

```
    beverages.peek();
```

give you "shoes" as it is at first.

```
    beverages.poll();
```

this will remove first element i.e., "shoes".

Now, beverages = ["ball"].

Comment: what should i change to beverages = "shoes"?

Comment: You can use stack data structure for that. Stack follows LIFO(last in first out)